# Simplifying $a_1^k\times a_2^{k+2}+a_3^k\times a_4^{k+2} \to a_2^2\times (a_1\times a_2)^k+a_4^2\times (a_3\times a_4)^k$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the following expression that Mathematica returned me after a calculation:

```
Res=1/77 (-107 3^(1 + k) 7^k + 199 2^(1 + k) 49^k)
```

As you can see, Mathematica did not really regroup the terms by power of $k$. What I would like is to see something like:

```
FixedRes=1/77 (-321*21^k + 398*98^k)
```

More generally I would like to do something like:

$$a_1^k*a_2^{k+2}+a_3^k*a_4^{k+2} \to a_2^2*(a_1*a_2)^k+a_4^2*(a_3*a_4)^k $$

How can I do it? I saw the function "Collect" but it does not solve the same issue I am asking. It is used to regroup terms a sum of terms in power of a *fixed* variable $x$ as a sum of separate $x^k$. I am somehow asking to regroup terms having a same power as variable.

Comment: This will be little hard without using `Hold` or `Inactive` and such family of commands. Because Mathematica will do automatic rewrite. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIVDU.png)  You see, it automatically writes  $3 (3\times7)^k$ as $3^{1+k} 7^k$ instead of $3\times 21^k$

Comment: ps. fixed your latex in title. In Latex `*` is not used for multiplication. Better to use $\times$

Comment: Try: `res // Expand // Simplify`

Comment: @DanielHuber it does not work. They want same output as `FixedRes`

Comment: I get, from `Res // Expand // Simplify` the output: `1/11 7^(-1 + k) (-107 3^(1 + k) + 199 2^(1 + k) 7^k)`.  My version of MMA is 13.2

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, I get same. But this is not really the same as they want which is `1/77 (-321*21^k + 398*98^k)` different forms. Without using `Hold` and such, I do not see how it is possible to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care efficiencies,

```
powerRule1[power_] :=
    {
        IgnoringInactive[x_^(power*k1_.+rest1_.)*y_^(power*k2_.+rest2_.)]:>
            With[ {var = x^k1*y^k2//Simplify},
                If[ IntegerQ[x]||IntegerQ[y],
                    Inactivate[var^power,Power|Sqrt],
                    var^power
                ]
            ]*x^rest1*y^rest2
    };
```

```
res//.powerRule1[k]
```

[image]

---

This is a function I wrote long time ago and have never tested carefully.

```
powerCollect`kernel[][expr_] :=
    expr//ReplaceRepeated[powerRule`collect[]];
powerCollect`kernel[power_][expr_] :=
    expr//ReplaceRepeated[powerRule`collect[power]];
powerCollect`kernel[power1_,powerRest__][expr_] :=
    powerCollect`kernel[powerRest][
        powerCollect`kernel[power1][expr]
    ];

powerCollect//Options={"wrapper"->Activate};
powerCollect[powers___,opts:OptionsPattern[]][expr_]:=
    powerCollect`kernel[powers][expr]//OptionValue["wrapper"];

powerRule`collect[power_] :=
    {
        IgnoringInactive[x_^(power*k1_.+rest1_.)*y_^(power*k2_.+rest2_.)]:>
            With[ {var = x^k1*y^k2//Simplify},
                If[ IntegerQ[x]||IntegerQ[y],
                    Inactivate[var^power,Power|Sqrt],
                    var^power
                ]
            ]*x^rest1*y^rest2,
        powerRule`mergeNestedPower,
        powerRule`cancelMinus
    };

powerRule`collect[] = {
    IgnoringInactive[x_^(power_*k1_.+rest1_.)*y_^(power_*k2_.+rest2_.)]:>
        With[ {var = x^k1*y^k2//Simplify},
            If[ IntegerQ[x]||IntegerQ[y],
                Inactivate[var^power,Power|Sqrt],
                var^power
            ]
        ]*x^rest1*y^rest2,
    powerRule`mergeNestedPower,
    powerRule`cancelMinus
};

powerRule`mergeNestedPower = 
    IgnoringInactive[(x_^a_)^b_]:>x^(a*b);

powerRule`cancelMinus =
    IgnoringInactive[(-1*rest_.)^(k_Integer*a_.+b_.)]/;EvenQ@k:>
        (-1)^b*rest^(k*a+b);
```

[image]